# MSVCR90.dll Отсутствует в системе

Tags: windows, dll

Не запускается из программ. В логах видно такую строчку

> MSVCR90!initterm

Как я понял, отсутствует эта ДЛЛ в системе. Действительно, я её не нашел в папке Windows, зато она есть, и не в одном экземпляре, в недрах  winsxs.
Установка

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 пакет обновления 1 (SP1)
>    Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 и т.д.

Не помогла.

**Win7 64bit.**

Comment: Потому что надо ставить vcredist нужной версии.

Comment: А в моем случае, какая нужная версия?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Устанавливать по идее overkill, надо просто положить все зависимости в каталог с исполнимым файлом.

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor: Каким компилятором вы компилировали? От него и берите.

Comment: @VladD не оверкилл, а штатный способ получения рантайма, если его нет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Это глобальное решение локальной проблемы. Всё, что нужно программе (за исключением особо жирных вещей наподобие фреймворка .NET или DirectX) должно быть, насколько я понимаю, в каталоге инсталляции.

Comment: @VladD Я не компилировал ничего. Я устанавливал готовый продукт. Раньше все работало,потом переустановил систему, и эту программу. Теперь не запускается. Обновления ничего не могли испортить? Если эта ДЛЛ есть в недрах winsxs, значит же она присутствовала в системе.

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor: Ну, хм. Тогда это по сути баг в программе: она должна таскать с собой всё необходимое. Вы её инсталлировали как надо, или просто скопировали откуда-нибудь?

Answer (score 1):

Все VCRedist за все годы для всех разрядностей:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=3387

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/confirmation.aspx?id=21254

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/confirmation.aspx?id=15336

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14632

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=30679

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=40784

https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Скачай и поставь всё. И 32-х битные тоже.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки. Всё равно не помогло. Кажется мне что это случилось после установки одного из обновлений.
Перед этим я систему вообще не обновлял и эта программа запускалась. После переустановки установил несколько обновлений и теперь вот такая ситуация.

Comment: Тогда попробуй дообновиться вообще до конца с несколькими перезагрузками. Просто на vcredist ещё обновы тоже должны прилететь. Может поможет.